# How to calculate rolling Volume Profile using Pandas faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

### Problem

I am doing some market analysis and as a part of technical analysis, I am using a "rolling" [Volume Profile](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502040-volume-profile/) indicator. It calculates the price level with the highest volume in last x candles (`window`) and it's calculated every candle.

This creates an issue, because the size of the dataframe values that needs to be processed is multiplied by the `window`. E.g. if the dataframe has `1000` rows and the `window` is set to `10`, it has to process `10000` rows.

I usually use `window` parameter between **5 - 30** and usuall dataframe size is **1.5 - 2.5 milions of rows** *(because it is so slow, I was never able to set window larger than 30)*.

I need the "point of control" only, which is the price level with the **highest volume** in the `window`.

[image: vrp_tradingview]

This is how the implementation looks on the chart:
[image: vrp_real]

---

### Question

- Is there any way how to speed up the process ommiting the "costly" `for` loop and leverage from `pandas` or `numpy` functions?
- Is it possible to group values with same price level faster than using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` method?
- Is it even possible to lower the processing time under `120 sec / 1M` rows?

---

#### A selection of the used tech

- Python `3.10`
- Pandas `1.4.4`
- numpy `1.24.2`
- running in `AWS ECS Fargate` (but results on local are quite similar); 1 vCPU and 8 GB or memory *(threading/parallelism might not be so effective)*

---

### Algorithm variables explained

- **point of control**: the price level with the highest volume in period
- **window**: number of candles used to calculate volume profile (last x candles)
- **precision**: price level that I round price to (if set to `10` => `13 -> 10`; set to `100` => `18421 -> 18400`)

---

### Current implementation

*Note: I have removed some comments from the code*
*Note: I understand the inaccurate way of the calculations, however I do not have tick-data to do the more precise calculation*

Dataframe example

```py
              datetime    close     volume
0  2019-11-05 22:17:00  9311.73  17.535066
1  2019-11-05 22:18:00  9306.09  19.708704
2  2019-11-05 22:19:00  9307.72  17.067911
3  2019-11-05 22:20:00  9303.72  39.139451
4  2019-11-05 22:21:00  9300.23  19.286789
5  2019-11-05 22:22:00  9300.43  49.699525
6  2019-11-05 22:23:00  9299.52   8.923734
7  2019-11-05 22:24:00  9299.82  27.646121
8  2019-11-05 22:25:00  9307.83  14.054908
9  2019-11-05 22:26:00  9314.66  16.678026
10 2019-11-05 22:27:00  9317.17  13.971519
11 2019-11-05 22:28:00  9323.35  30.626054
12 2019-11-05 22:29:00  9323.48  31.870815
13 2019-11-05 22:30:00  9323.41  12.434114
14 2019-11-05 22:31:00  9327.88   6.688897
15 2019-11-05 22:32:00  9332.30   9.494066
16 2019-11-05 22:33:00  9328.17  11.473973
17 2019-11-05 22:34:00  9324.59  16.432248
18 2019-11-05 22:35:00  9319.58  15.865908
19 2019-11-05 22:36:00  9318.79  10.796839
```

This locates/computes the POC

```py
# Now, create a rolling maximum of last x candles only
def get_poc(input_df,
            precision):
    profile = input_df.groupby('close')[['volume']].sum()

    point_of_control = profile['volume'].idxmax()

    # In order to draw line just in the middle of the bar with the highest
    # value we need to add half of the precision to the value

    point_of_control_middle = point_of_control + (precision / 2)

    return point_of_control_middle
```

Main def

```py
def generate_vrp(input_df,
                 precision,
                 window):
    logger.info("> Generating volume profiles (VRP)")

    num_rows = input_df.shape[0]

    # Price levels
    price_levels = pd.DataFrame(columns=['datetime', 'vrp_level'])

    input_df['close'] = (input_df['close'] / precision).round() * precision

    # In order to get to the last value, we need to do :"- window + 1"
    for i in tqdm(range(1, num_rows)):

        if i < window:
            rows = input_df[0:i].copy()
        else:
            rows = input_df[i - window:i].copy()

        # Get datetime from last row in the dataset
        last_row = rows.iloc[-1]

        # Get the volume profile
        new_data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': last_row['datetime'],
                                 'vrp_level': get_poc(rows,
                                                      precision)},
                                index=[0])

        price_levels = pd.concat([price_levels, new_data], ignore_index=True)

    return price_levels
```

Method calling

```py
window = 30 # 10 candles
precision = 10 # the volume profile "step" is 100
generate_vrp(df, precision, window)
```

Example response *(just column with datetime and vrp_level/poc)*

- precision: `10`
- window: `30`

```py
              datetime  vrp_level
0  2019-11-05 22:17:00     9315.0
1  2019-11-05 22:18:00     9315.0
2  2019-11-05 22:19:00     9315.0
3  2019-11-05 22:20:00     9315.0
4  2019-11-05 22:21:00     9305.0
5  2019-11-05 22:22:00     9305.0
6  2019-11-05 22:23:00     9305.0
7  2019-11-05 22:24:00     9305.0
8  2019-11-05 22:25:00     9305.0
9  2019-11-05 22:26:00     9305.0
10 2019-11-05 22:27:00     9305.0
11 2019-11-05 22:28:00     9305.0
12 2019-11-05 22:29:00     9305.0
13 2019-11-05 22:30:00     9305.0
14 2019-11-05 22:31:00     9305.0
15 2019-11-05 22:32:00     9305.0
16 2019-11-05 22:33:00     9305.0
17 2019-11-05 22:34:00     9305.0
18 2019-11-05 22:35:00     9305.0
19 2019-11-05 22:36:00     9305.0
20 2019-11-05 22:37:00     9325.0
```

And profiling from [scalene](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene) shows, that potential issue might be the `groupby` and `get_poc` functions.
[image: scalene-profiling]

### Possible solutions / tried approaches

- ❌: tried; not worked
- : and idea I am going to test
- : did not completely solved the problem, but helped towards the solution
- ✅: working solution

##### ❌ Test bfolkens/py-market-profile

The idea is to test [py-market-profile](https://github.com/bfolkens/py-market-profile) instead of `get_poc` method. In my local tests, it showed extremely good performance results in volume profile calculations.

Tests results after this implementation are not... good. Scalene points out this line as the bottleneck `mp_slice = mp[i - window:i]`. **It's worse than the initial solution.**

```py
def generate_vrp(df, precision, window):
    num_rows = df.shape[0]

    price_levels = pd.DataFrame(columns=['datetime', 'vrp_level'])
    df['close'] = (df['close'] / precision).round() * precision
    df = df.rename(columns={'close': 'Close',
                            'volume': 'Volume'})
    mp = MarketProfile(df)

    for i in tqdm(range(1, num_rows)):
        if i < window:
            mp_slice = mp[0:i]
        else:
            mp_slice = mp[i - window:i]

        poc = mp_slice.poc_price
        last_row = df.iloc[i]
        new_data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': last_row['datetime'],
                                 'vrp_level': poc},
                                index=[0])

        price_levels = pd.concat([price_levels, new_data], ignore_index=True)

    return price_levels
```

[image: scalene-profile]

---

### Solutions benchmark

- Using 1k, 10k, 20k, 50k and 100k dataframe rows; measured using `timeit`
  [image: benchmarks]

---

*Even if I don't get any answer, I will continue testing and editing until I find a solution and hopefully help someone else.*

Comment: I try to run your example and it says the `datetime` column is missing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I have removed too much columns from the example df. I am gonna fix this now.

Comment: hi @FN_ this is interesting, I am looking for something similar although for reliable methods to calculate vah and val instead and on higher timeframes. were you able to get consistency with what tradingview would show for them and your python output?

Comment: @NikhilMulley ummm, pretty much yes.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand you question right. Perhaps you can use `pd.DataFrame.rolling()`:

```py
window = 10 # 10 candles
precision = 100 # the volume profile "step" is 100

df["close"] = (df["close"] / precision).round() * precision

def roll_func(x):
    profile = df.iloc[x.index].groupby("close")["volume"].sum()
    return profile.idxmax()

df['vrp_level_2'] = df.rolling(window, min_periods=1)['volume'].apply(roll_func) + (precision / 2)
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
              datetime   close     volume  vrp_level_2
0  2019-11-05 22:17:00  9300.0  17.535066       9350.0
1  2019-11-05 22:18:00  9300.0  19.708704       9350.0
2  2019-11-05 22:19:00  9300.0  17.067911       9350.0
3  2019-11-05 22:20:00  9300.0  39.139451       9350.0
4  2019-11-05 22:21:00  9300.0  19.286789       9350.0
5  2019-11-05 22:22:00  9300.0  49.699525       9350.0
6  2019-11-05 22:23:00  9300.0   8.923734       9350.0
7  2019-11-05 22:24:00  9300.0  27.646121       9350.0
8  2019-11-05 22:25:00  9300.0  14.054908       9350.0
9  2019-11-05 22:26:00  9300.0  16.678026       9350.0
10 2019-11-05 22:27:00  9300.0  13.971519       9350.0
11 2019-11-05 22:28:00  9300.0  30.626054       9350.0
12 2019-11-05 22:29:00  9300.0  31.870815       9350.0
13 2019-11-05 22:30:00  9300.0  12.434114       9350.0
14 2019-11-05 22:31:00  9300.0   6.688897       9350.0
15 2019-11-05 22:32:00  9300.0   9.494066       9350.0
16 2019-11-05 22:33:00  9300.0  11.473973       9350.0
17 2019-11-05 22:34:00  9300.0  16.432248       9350.0
18 2019-11-05 22:35:00  9300.0  15.865908       9350.0
19 2019-11-05 22:36:00  9300.0  10.796839       9350.0
```

---

EDIT: Possible solution using `collections.deque` (without `DataFrame.rolling`):

```py
from collections import deque

window = 10 # 10 candles
precision = 100 # the volume profile "step" is 100

df["close"] = (df["close"] / precision).round() * precision

indices = deque([], maxlen=window)
out = []
for i in df.index:
    indices.append(i)
    out.append(df.iloc[indices].groupby("close")["volume"].sum().idxmax())

df['vrp_level_2'] = out
df['vrp_level_2'] += (precision / 2)
print(df)
```

Comment: It seems like you did it correctly, thanks. Using `.apply()` on dataframes is something I still need to learn. Do you have a recommendation for a good tutorial or guide?

Comment: @FN_ The [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) is good start. Pandas has rolling functions so it's the first thing to try (note: the `.apply()` in this context is [window function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html#window-generic)).

Comment: Thanks/díky Andrej. :) The performance is much better than using my tries. Do you think it is possible to lower the exec time even more? My goal will be around 120 seconds per 1M rows. Even just a hint will help, I'll try the rest myself.

Comment: @FN_ I slightly changed the code (to not create DataFrame every rolling interation, just Series. Should be slightly faster)

Comment: @FN_ As a hint, maybe multiprocessing could be useful here (~1 mio rows on 16 thread machine: each thread could process ~60k rows in under <100 seconds + time to join the results).

Comment: Slightly? :D It cut more than half of the runtime, good job, thanks!

About multiprocessing - unfortunately I run my code on single core/thread VMs :(

Comment: @FN_ I've added another solution using `collections.deque`

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it, but it has similar results as the one using `DataFrame.rolling`. I think I will stick to it.